# Strings Created inside a Java For Each Loop eligible for GC

Tags: java, arrays

Coming from different languages, this seems to confuse me.

```
String [] names = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
for (String n : names){
    n = new String(n+"hello");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names)); // [A, B, C]
```

`names` still has original values [A,B,C], I believe this is due to immutability, but does this mean I have created three garbage collectible Strings when I iterated through the array?

Yet this code does modify array?

```
Car [] cars = { new Car("red"), new Car("green") };
    for(int i=0; i<cars.length; i++){
        Car c = cars[i];
        c.color ="black";
    }

    for(int i=0; i<cars.length; i++){
        Car c = cars[i];
        System.out.println(c.color);    //prints black, black
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is because strings are immutable in Java, and yes, the three strings created by `n + "hello"` will be thrown away.

Comment: Is this java? Look not correct?

Comment: The title is not helpful to future visitors; it should reflect the problem you're trying to solve; not be a statement of your existing understanding.  Think of it this way, if you were searching for an answer to your problem, would you search for "Java Arrays Confusion"?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "I believe this is due to immutability"? Immutability of what: (1) array (you can change it simply via `names[index]=newValue`, (2) `n` you just saw that your code was executed without any errors/exceptions, also if you would print value of `n` inside loop you would see that it was changed (but simply didn't affect array because `n` holds same value as `names[i]` but *is not the same variable*).

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with `String`'s immutability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code

```
for (String n : names){
    n = new String(n+"hello");
}
```

is same as

```
for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
    String n = names[i];
    n = new String(n+"hello");
}
```

So as you see assigning `n` new value can't affect array. And yes, at end of each iteration String created via `new String(n+"hello");` will be eligible for garbage collection.

But since `n` by default holds same object as `names[i]` you can use it to change state of held object. For instance if your array would be array of `Persons`, via `n` you would be able to change property like `age` of stored Person

```
n.setAge(42);
```

You can also assign new value to `n`,

```
n = new Person("Jack", 40);
```

but this doesn't mean that you are assigning new value to `names[i]` because `n` and `names[i]` are different variables.

Maybe this will help you a little

when `n = names[i]` situation looks like this:

```
names[i] ----+       +--------+
             |       | Person |
             +------>+--------+
             |       | name   | //Adam 
       n ----+       | age    | //30
                     +--------+
```

so both variables (references) hold same instance, which allows you to manipulate it from both variables (if you change `name` or `age` via `n` you will be also to see this change also via `names[i]` because they hold same object)

But if you do

```
n = new Person("Jack", 42);
```

you are assigning new object only to `n`, not to `names[i]`, so situation will be

```
                     +--------+
                     | Person |
names[i] ----------->+--------+
                     | name   | //Adam 
                     | age    | //30
                     +--------+

                     +--------+
                     | Person |
       n ----------->+--------+
                     | name   | //Jack
                     | age    | //42
                     +--------+
```

which means that array (`names[i]`) doesn't change.

In short via `n` you can't put `new` elements to array, but you can change state of existing elements.

Comment: Great analysis - I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes you did create 3 GC eligible `String` objects inside the loop, because while you created the 3 `String`'s, they are immediately out of context when the loop exits, because the variable n only exists within the for each loop.

As a side note, you can't change the values within the names array while you are iterating over it using a for-each construct.

```
String [] names = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
for(String n : names){
    //There is no way you can modify the array within the loop,
    //You can only read out of it.
    //Because n only has meaning inside the loop, any changes to it,
    //only have meaning inside the loop.

     n = "The Spanish Inquisition";

    //No one expects the above assignment to change the value of
    //names array value that n was originally, because n is just a
    //reference of the value held within the array.
}
return names;
```

If you do try to modify `names` within the loop it should throw a ConcurrentModificationException. The `String`'s that were created within the loop, are out of context as soon as you exit the loop, and so are eligible for GC.

Updated Code Explanation:

Your updated code works because you are accessing each object within the array individually, changing each object which then implicitly updates the value in the array. Using a normal for loop to do this is fine, because you are using something external to the object you are iterating over to control the iteration (in this case a variable called i).

You are essentially doing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
    cars[i].color = "black";
}
```

Because you don't use `Car c = new Car(cars[i]);` you get the actual `Car` object instance that is contained inside the array, not a copy of the `Car` object contained inside the array which is what you seem to be expecting to get.

You won't get a different object reference back unless you specifically invoke a constructor. For example you could do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
    Car c = new Car();
    c.setColor(cars[i].getColor());
}
```

which would not modify the value of the car object inside the `cars` array.

Comment: Great, I added code to the post, Can you explain why the added piece does change the array?

Comment: @user1529412 does my explanation that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't changed the array `names` at any point. `n` is simply a variable you are using to iterate through all the values contained within `names`.  Assuming foreach was a valid keyword...  you need simply `for`

Comment: But n isn't really a variable, it's a reference, which I would like to think of it as a pointer even thought Java doesn't admit it. I think  Chthonic Project cleared up my confusion, the ref simply creates a new object which in this case would be just garbage collected.

Comment: @user1529412 : The way Java works is by using references (which are somewhat different from pointers). When you say `n = names[i] + "hello"`, it simply stores the string `names[i] + "hello"`, and uses `n` to refer to that address. The actual i'th element of the `names` array remains untouched.